# How can you algebraically determine if a curve is symmetric about $y=-x$?

Tags: proof-verification, graphing-functions, symmetry

If I have a curve implicitly defined by say $x^2+xy+y^2=1$, then it is clear that it is symmetric about $y=x$ because if I interchange x's with y's, then I have the exact same equation.

However, how would one adapt a similar kind of mentality to show that a curve is symmetric about $y=-x$?

It seems awfully tempting to say that you replace $x$ with $-y$ and $y$ with $-x$, but I am not sure if this is valid. It's worked with the few examples I've thought of so far like $xy=1$ and $x^2+xy+y^2=1$.

Comment: rotate the curve with 90degs and then apply the standard method?

Comment: I can see that this would work. However, I would like to know if the idea I had was valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry in line $y=-x$ maps point $(x,y)$ to $(-y,-x)$ (and vice versa), so you indeed can simply replace $x$ by $-y$, $y$ by $-x$ and check whether you get the same equality.